# R: Improving output

Tags: r, dataframe, output, time-series

Here is an example code I created with the vars package  to test for stationarity:

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
Canada <- data.frame(Canada)

test = function(x) {
  adf <- ur.df(x, type = "trend", selectlags = "BIC")
  adf.out <- format(round(c(adf@teststat[1], head(adf@cval,1)[,c(1,2,3)]), 2), nsmall = 3)
  adf.comment <- if(adf.out[1] >= adf.out[3]) {"Yes"} else {"No"}

  kpss <- ur.kpss(x, type ="tau", use.lag = adf@lags)
  kpss.out <- format(round(c(kpss@teststat[1],head(kpss@cval, 1)[,c(4,2,1)]), 2), nsmall = 3)
  kpss.comment <- if(adf.out[1] >= adf.out[3]) {"Yes"} else {"No"}

  out <- c(adf.out, adf.comment, kpss.out, kpss.comment)
  out
}

test(Canada["prod"][,1])
```

Output:

```
> test(Canada["prod"][,1])
             1pct     5pct    10pct                       1pct     5pct    10pct          
"-2.020" "-4.040" "-3.450" "-3.150"     "No"  "0.490"  "0.220"  "0.150"  "0.120"     "No"
```

Why are there "" around the numbers and how can I remove them?

Comment: `format` converts them to characters.

Comment: Okay, the format solves the problem if I don't include the comments. Note that I updated the script with "adf.comment" and "kpss.comment". When introducing these into the output, the problem appears, again, for all items?

Comment: If any element in `c(adf.out, adf.comment, kpss.out, kpss.comment)` is a character vector, then the resulting vector will also be a character type.

Comment: you want to remove the quotation marks in the R console or in an external file you produce? if its just the console why you want to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix two R data types in one object `string` and `numeric`. R can not carry two data types in one simple object. The result is that it convert the `numeric` to `string` - this is shown by the quotation marks. When you convert the `string` to `numeric` you create for the sting `NA` which means a information loss so R choose the to convert everything in a `string`.

You can transform your data to a `data.frame` (see below). Because a `data.frame` is a complex data type, which can hold each column a different data.types. I don't recommend you for optical purpose to use `data.frame`. If you want to calculate with this numbers you can later convert a `string` to `numeric` with the function `as.numeric(out)`.

```
test = function(x) {
  adf <- ur.df(x, type = "trend", selectlags = "BIC")
  adf.out <- format(round(c(adf@teststat[1], head(adf@cval,1)[,c(1,2,3)]), 2), nsmall = 3)
  adf.comment <- if(adf.out[1] >= adf.out[3]) {"Yes"} else {"No"}

  kpss <- ur.kpss(x, type ="tau", use.lag = adf@lags)
  kpss.out <- format(round(c(kpss@teststat[1],head(kpss@cval, 1)[,c(4,2,1)]), 2), nsmall = 3)
  kpss.comment <- if(adf.out[1] >= adf.out[3]) {"Yes"} else {"No"}

  out <- c(adf.out, adf.comment, kpss.out, kpss.comment)
  out <- data.frame(matrix(out, nrow=1, dimnames=list(NULL, names(out))))
  return(out)
}

test(Canada["prod"][,1])[,-1]
```

Comment: That seems to help, thank you! I only removed the last "out <-" so that I get the output when calling the function. Assume I would loop over a few items, in Canada i.e. a few variables. How can I avoid that the first column is always printed?

Comment: you're right...it is even better to return the data. You can drop columns with negative index. see my edit. If you find this answer useful it is also good practice to upvote the answer ;)